# No configuration found for the specified action in Struts 2

Tags: jsp, struts2, forms-authentication, struts2-namespace

I have done validation for my login for. It's working fine but after entering correct `username` and `password`, no action is performed, and nor opening JSP page after successful  login.

**Here is my Login form:**

```
         <s:form validate="true"   action="login">
        <br>
         <table class="bg" cellspacing="0">
        <tr class="logindiv">
          <td >
          </td>`enter code here`
         <td>

       Sign In
       </td>
         </tr>

           <tr>
          <td>
          <s:textfield label="Username" name="obj2.user" cssStyle="height:25px;                   width:150px;"></s:textfield>
         </td>
              </tr>



            <tr>
       <td>
       <s:password label="Password" name="obj2.pass"  cssStyle="height:25px;width:150px;"></s:password>
           </td>
            </tr>

                <tr>
                 <td>

             <center>&nbsp;
               <s:submit value="Login" cssClass="login"></s:submit>
              </center>

                  </td>
                 </tr>


            </table>

               </s:form>
```

**`struts.xml`:**

```
          <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
         <!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
          "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
            "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">



     <struts>

          <constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />

           <package name="default" namespace="/" extends="struts-default">
       <action name="login" class="IndianUserActionModule.indianAction" method="Login">
          <result name="input">index.jsp</result>
         <result name="success">IndianHome.jsp</result>
         <result name="fail">index.jsp</result>
      </action>

         </package>

        </struts>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your struts configuration you map the action to a particular namespace of the package config. But in your JSP form you map an action to a *default* namespace. These are different namespaces and your action config isn't found in the *default* namespace, so it fails. You should use namespace attribute of your `s:form` tag to specify a namespace used to map the action. For example

```
<s:form validate="true" namespace="/"  action="login">
```

There's an [example](http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/struts-2-namespace-configuration-example-and-explanation) that would let you better understand the namespaces concept.